# Google Image Result with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm building a PHP web app which requires a dynamic list of images, based on a MySQL database. For example, if the database consisted of "house", "car", and "plane", I'd like to display three images of a house, a car, and a plane. I do not want to store these images locally, because the database will be constantly changing. Instead, I'd like it to query Google Images using PHP and then generate an image URL that I can echo to HTML to display the image. Even better, if it could be customized with a random image index (so it won't use the first image every time), that would be even better.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I have doubts about whether it will work well. A Google Images result could be unusable because it shows the wrong thing, or the object is hard to identify. I would feel uneasy fetching data from a source that could change constantly. But maybe my fears are unfounded.

Answer (score 0):

Google used to have an image search api (http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/) but that has been deprecated. If you need a reliable method I would not advise using anything that is deprecated but that is up to you and your application spec.

Another way would be to curl www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q= and scrape the html that is returned. I believe that this is against Google's TOS so again use with caution.

I would suggest looking into other services than Google. Here is Bings api doc (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251072.aspx) as an example.

Comment: Does anyone have some sample code? I'm fine with scraping, and it doesn't have to be randomized, that would just be a value-add.